# How do I clean dripped paint from a wood floor?

Tags: wood, painting, cleaning

I've painted the skirting boards in this room and the paint has dripped on to a pretty fresh stained and varnished floor.

How can I get these paint marks off the floor without damaging the new stain or varnish?

[image: dripped paint]
[image: paint splatter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 5-in-1 painter's tool (e.g. Richard brand) to scrape them off.  These tools have an edge that is slightly curved and rounded so that you can scrape without gouging a surface. I've used this for removing burnt-on gunk from a frying pan, without damaging the pan.

You may find that the paint does not actually adhere to the varnish very well and the droplets just pop off, which is the ideal situation. If they adhere stubbornly, you may nevertheless be able to use the tool to plane them flat, reducing these droplets of dry paint into essentially thin white stains. The remainder of the work can be done by a some light sanding with fine paper that won't cut through the varnish. Or, some solvent may be able to help with this last step. Acetone is almost certainly too strong for the varnish, but try isopropyl alcohol is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would hit it it with a scouring sponge, soap, and water before you touch it with a scraper.  If its latex paint it is not stuck for at least a few days.  If it is oil based then it is a little harder but still might come off with being wet for a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I used the chux wall sponges an soapy warm water an it came straight off with not much effort